# jQuery works in FireFox, but not in Chrome with Google Sites Gadget

Tags: sites

Please excuse my ignorance, but I am totally new to jQuery, HTML, Javascript, and so on. Network backround.

I am inserting a html file into a Google Gadget for a Google site. What it is supposed to do is display 4 boxes that reveal a partial picture and a button to expand the picture. When you click on the button the box is supposed to enlarge and reveal the whole picture plus some text. This works fine in Firefox when I have this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

but not in chrome.

I have uploaded all of these necessary files in order this to work in my Google Site to my Google Drive. I have shared the jQuery.js file in my drive and copied it to my html file. When I replace the line above with this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://docs.google.com/a/chartwellreit.ca/uc?id=0B7EcQSX7GqjAREtlOXBOQmVRaUE"></script>
```

It works fine in Chrome, but not in FireFox.

Please let me know if you need anymore info.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery

To load a hosted library, copy and paste the HTML snippet for that library (shown below) in your web page. For instance, to load jQuery, embed this snippet:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

snippet in your web page.